Pass an array from groovy to bash
I use Jenkins for k6 tests CI/CD.
In my pipeline I have the code:
def users = ["user1","user2","user3"]
sh """
export MY_USERS=${users.join(' ')}
./start.sh
"""

In my bash script I have:
SCRIPT_USERS=$MY_USERS

for user in $MY_USERS; do
  eval "$PARAMS $K6 run $user.js -o xk6-influxdb \
  --out web-dashboard=port=0\&report=$DIR/${user}.html" &
done

However, in logs I got SCRIPT_USERS=user1
How can I get my values in a bash variable?
I need all the values.
Tried different ways of passing the variables but no worked.

Didn't work anyway

Do you want the result in a bash variable, or in a bash array? If a variable is sufficient, as your script suggests,  you have to define a way how the array elements show up in your bash code. In your case, this would be user1 user2 user3. If you want the result to end up in a bash array, you have to think of a serialization format for the Groovy array, and you have to de-serialize it in bash.

In the Groovy script, you are constructing a script dynamically. The equivalent after users.join(' ') is executed is
export MY_USERS=user1 user2 user3

which exports the name MY_USERS after it is assigned the value user1, but also exports the undefined names user2 and user3.
You need to quote ${users.join(' ')} so that the entire result is part of the single assignment to MY_USERS.
def users = ["user1","user2","user3"]
sh """
export MY_USERS="${users.join(' ')}"
./start.sh
"""

Your actual bash script is more or less fine. SCRIPT_USERS isn't necessary; you can just use MY_USERS directly as you are anyway. eval may not be necessary, and you should work to avoid it if you can. There is a general issue of relying on a space-separated string to correctly represent an array of arbitrary strings, but assuming your user names are "simple" (nothing except alphanumeric characters), you can get away with it.

Thank you, it finally worked. Will try to check out other options instead of eval as well.

I would have said to just drop eval altogether as unnecessary, but I suspect that PARAMS has a value like PARAMS="x=1 y=2". Look into the env command; something like env -S "$PARAMS" "$K6" run ... may work.
